# Jboss url path debugging

Tags: tomcat, jboss

I am trying to debug a spring 3.2 application that works fine under tomcat version 7

Trying to make it work under Jboss AS7 has been a complete nightmare, it does some url path name mapping.

Under Jboss is there any way of seeing how the url or pathname is processed?

I have tried setting   level for the category of org.apache.tomcat to be ALL

in standalone.xml,  I assumed that I would get some type of diagnostic about tomcat processing but noting.  I just want to see how the path name is processed.

Comment: can you explain what you mean by pathname processing and what it is that you're trying to find?

Comment: What I am trying to find out is what Jboss string and spring are expecting!

For example if I have jboss configured to expect a url of /foo/bar and  Spring setup to intercept url of the form /foobar, its a mistake and will never work. 

I would like both tools to say, I am expecting a url of the foo xxxyyz, as a tool user I can then work out what is going wrong.  currently all I am getting is a 404 error.  Since my program worked under Tomcat 7, it must be a configuration issue,  I am just trying to find out what it is.

Comment: Ok, added an answer based on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JBoss will show in the console/logs what it is expecting. Say you have a web app configured as `/yourcontextroot`, there should be this in the console output:

```
11:26:08,269 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS018210: Registering web context: /yourcontextroot
```

There are two things that have an impact in your case, a) the application context root, that you can set with jboss-web.xml, and b) spring context root, which comes *on top of* what you configure to jboss. So if you have configured /foo/bar to jboss and /foobar to Spring, your application responds at /foo/bar/foobar.

To use jboss-web.xml to configure context root, it needs to be placed in WEB-INF (assuming you have a .war, same as web.xml) and have content like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web>
  <context-root>/yourcontextroot</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

Comment: I am using the servlet 3.0 

My start up code is
public void onStartup(ServletContext container) {
  appContext.setConfigLocation("/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml");

                final ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = container.addServlet("appServlet", new DispatcherServlet(appContext));
 final MultipartConfigElement multipartConfigElement = new MultipartConfigElement(null, 5000000, 5000000, 0);                dispatcher.setMultipartConfig(multipartConfigElement);
  dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
                dispatcher.addMapping("/");
}

Comment: I do not wish people to debug my code, thats my job,  I could just do with pointing in the right direction.
Thanks eis for the pointer,  I shall try that tonight.
Dave.